# SQL ignores 2nd criterion in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Why would the second criterion in this WHERE clause be ignored?

```
$old = time() - 2592000;
$sql_deleteold = ("DELETE FROM todolist WHERE status='done' AND stamp < $old");
mysql_query($sql_deleteold);
```

I want to delete data from the database older than 30 days with the status "done".

Instead it will go deleting all rows with the status "done".

Comment: What second statement? If you mean the second conditional expression, then it won't be "ignored". Without a testcase (or schema - what is `stamp`?), you cannot be helped further.

Comment: What datatype is `stamp`? If it is a MySQL `DATETIME` type, you will need `FROM_UNIXTIME($old)`

Comment: In an attempt to create an analogy between the parts of a SQL statement and a written sentence in English, the parts of a SQL statement are called `clauses` and the parts of the clause are called `predicates`. I assume here he is meaning the second predicate.

Comment: Jim, you are correct. I've edited to possibly use the terms that a Google user might use when searching to find the answer.

Comment: @p.campbell: "Criteria" is the plural form.

Comment: I too am curious what the schema for the todolist table looks like. Is 'stamp' a TIMESTAMP field? or is it a BIGINT?

Comment: since mysql timestamp differs from php timestamp i decided to fill it with the php timestamp. Its a standard varchar 255 field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your question is referring to the "second statement" in the SQL query?

With this assumption, the problem with all rows being deleted with the status "done" is because the WHERE filters are similar to conditional statements like the ones used in "If" statements.

If the first statement, or WHERE filter is true, then execute.

Try doing the following:

```
$old = time() - 2592000;
$sql_deleteold = ("DELETE FROM todolist WHERE (status='done' AND stamp < $old)");
mysql_query($sql_deleteold);
```

You also might want to verify the value of $old and compare it to the values in the 'stamp' field of your table, to be sure that there are some rows that have a value in the 'stamp' field that are greater than the value of $old.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried debugging your query? Rather than deleting the query try selecting the values:

```
SELECT * FROM todolist WHERE status = 'done' AND stamp < $old
```

Does it select the results you expect? If it doesn't keep tweaking it till it does, then attempt to delete the records.

Comment: that famous "SELECT * FRIN table" syntax

Comment: and the not-quite-so-famous `$ odl` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a quoting issue. To be sure, try:

```
$sql_deleteold = "DELETE FROM `todolist` WHERE `status`='done' AND `stamp` < '".$old."';";
```

Also when you insert fields, do you set the `stamp` field with php $time()$ function, or is it set by SQL functions? Because the time representation may be different depending on the type of the `stamp` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing `SELECT stamp FROM todolist` and see what you get.  Presumably, they will be values less than `time() = 2592000`.